# Python webapp2 project structure configuration

Tags: python, python-2.7, webapp2, google-app-engine-python

I'd like to organize my project like the next structure but I have a problem when I try to test it

[image]

in the handlers folder I have a file named: Base.py and one class inside:

```
 def get_success_reponse(**kwargs):
     kwargs.update(
       dict(
        status="SUCCESS",
       )
     )
     return kwargs

 class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
       property = 0
```

in the same folder handlers I have another file named: EchoHandler.py and one class inside

```
import Base

class EchoHandler(Base.BaseHandler):
    def post(self): 
        logger.info("test")       
        data = json.loads(self.request.body)
        echo = data.get("echo")
    return self.json_data(get_success_reponse(echo))
```

My main.py file looks like

```
 import webapp2
 import config

 app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
      webapp2.Route('/x/v1/echo', handler='handlers.EchoHandler')
 ], debug=True, config=config.WEBAPP2CONFIG)
```

My app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /x/.*
  script: main.py  

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

**Problem**

When i do a POST request to http://localhost:8080/x/v1/echo sendind this data:

```
  {
    "echo": "Test"
  }
```

I receive a response "200 OK" but I don't get any json response, no log is written

If i change this "http://localhost:8080/x/v1/echo" to "http://localhost:8080/x/v1/echoasdfa" I receive 200 ok too.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but I'm going to answer it anyway. Make sure you are writing the data to the Response object in your handler before you return. You didn't provide the code for the `self.json_data()` method, but I assume you aren't writing the json data to the Response object even though you are returning it. Also, this may just be a typo in the question but it looks like your `return self.json_data(get_success_reponse(echo))` line is unindented. It should be at the same indentation level as the rest of the post() code.

In any event, try this:

```
import Base
import json

class EchoHandler(Base.BaseHandler):
    def post(self): 
        logger.info("test")       
        data = json.loads(self.request.body)
        echo = data.get("echo")

        # get the dict you want to convert to JSON
        echo_dict = get_success_response(echo)

        # convert it to a JSON string
        echo_json = json.dumps(echo_dict)

        # set the content type of the Response to JSON
        self.response.content_type = 'application/json'

        # write the JSON to the Response body and return the Response
        return self.response.write(echo_json)
```

You need to write data to the Response in order to send that data to the client. You don't *need* to return the response object after you write to it, but I like to do that anyway because I think it looks more clear.

Also, your Route looks messed up. Try changing your main.py to this:

```
 import webapp2
 import config

 # changed the lazy import line (handler='handlers.EchoHandler.EchoHandler')
 app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
      webapp2.Route('/x/v1/echo', handler='handlers.EchoHandler.EchoHandler')
 ], debug=True, config=config.WEBAPP2CONFIG)
```

or, the way I would do it is by actually importing the handler into the main.py:

```
 import webapp2
 import config
 from handlers import EchoHandler

 # note: no quotes around EchoHandler.EchoHandler
 app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
      webapp2.Route('/x/v1/echo', handler=EchoHandler.EchoHandler)
 ], debug=True, config=config.WEBAPP2CONFIG)
```